# Dependency Theory

Tags: database, database-design, dependencies, axiom, database-theory

Does anyone know of a good website, book or any other resources that would explain dependency theory well? I am stuck on a similar question to the one shown below:

Given

```
R   < A = {P,Q,R,S,T,U,Y },


gamma = {Y->S   …(1)
       Q->ST….(2)  

U-> Y……(3)
       S->R  …...(4)
```

> RS->T…….(5)   }>.
>
> ```
> RTP U->T  holds
> ```

Answer is:

```
U -> Y -> S -> RS -> T
aug (4) by S  S->R
```

Comment: If this is homework, please mark it as such.

Comment: @duffymo no its not homework it was an example given in class by the lecturer and he give the answer but I dont understand this, im really struggling to understand. The answer he give is now in the original post. I have a similar assignment questions but I don't understand this example or others he give in class, any advice or help you can provide would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to search for *functional dependency* instead of *dependency theory*. Wikipedia has an introductory article on [functional dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency). The expression "Y->S" means

- Y determines S, or
- if you know one value for 'Y', you
  know one value for 'S' (instead of
  two or three or seven values for 'S'), or
- if two tuples have the same value for 'Y', they'll also have the same value for 'S'

I'm not familiar with all the notation you posted. But I think you're asked to begin with a relation *R* and a set of functional dependencies *gamma* numbered 1 to 4 for reference.

```
Relation R = {P,Q,R,S,T,U,Y }

FD gamma = {Y->S   (1)
            Q->ST  (2)  
            U-> Y  (3)
            S->R   (4) }
```

This appears to be the "setup" for several problems. You're then asked to assume this additional functional dependency.

```
RS->T  (5)
```

Based on the setup and on that additional FD, you're supposed to prove that the functional dependency U->T holds. The lecturer's answer is "U -> Y -> S -> RS -> T", which I think is the chain of inferences the lecturer wants you to follow. You're given U->Y and Y->S to start with, so here's how that specific chain of inference goes.

1. **U->Y** and **Y->S**, therefore **U->S**. (transitivity, Lecturer's U->Y->S)
2. **S->R**, therefore **S->RS**. (augmentation, an intermediate step)
3. **U->S** and **S->RS**, therefore **U->RS**. (transitivity, Lecturer's U->Y->S->RS)
4. **U->RS** and **RS->T**, therefore **U->T**. (transitivity, Lecturer's U->Y->S->RS->T)

Comment: this helped me to understand a lot better, I am confused at 3.FD6 U->S and FD7 U->R, therefore FD8 U->RS, did you use augmentation?

Comment: at 3. you have used augmentation, am I wrong in thinking that it's like multiplying each side by U and then S?

Comment: @kb88: I edited my answer to make augmentation clear and to make it conform to the lecturer's note. I think that's what the lecturer had in mind by including "aug (4) by S S->R" in her answer. I'd take that to mean "augment S->R by S, giving SS->RS, which is the same as S->RS".

Comment: @kb88: I rewrote to make it look less like multiplication. You're better off not thinking of arithmetic. Augmentation deals with the union of sets, not multiplication of values or symbols. Augmenting S->R by S means "S union S -> R union S". "S union S" is just "S"; the two union operations simplify to "S->RS".

Comment: thanks for explaining this, it makes more sense but i find it difficult to know where to begin and see the pattern. i have two more examples that i'll have a look at and see if i can get to the same answer the lecturer has given. Thank you